# unit ball in $\ell^2$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that unit ball in $\ell^2$ is bounded (I've alrady shown that it's closed and non-compact). For some notation let $B$ denote the unit ball; that is,

$$
B:=\left\{x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in\ell^2:||x||\leq1\right\}.
$$

Clearly, the unit ball $B$ is contained in the open ball centered at $(0,0,0,\cdots)$ of radius $\pi$, denoted by $\operatorname{B}\left(\overrightarrow{0},\pi\right)$; that is,

$$
B:=\left\{x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in\ell^2:||x||\leq1\right\}\subseteq
\left\{x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in\ell^2:||x||<\pi\right\}=:\operatorname{B}\left(\overrightarrow{0},1\right).
$$

Is this correct? For some reason, we never mentioned what bounded meant or talked about it, so I did a google search and it said bounded in normed vector spaces means the set can be contained in an open ball...is this correct too? Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Isn’t any ball bounded in a metric space?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I'd hope so. I suppose this question is really me trying to clarify terminology by using it to prove something...if that make sense.

Comment: Generally we speak of the $open$ unit ball $\{x:\|x\|<1\}$ and the $closed$ unit ball $\{x:\|x\|\le 1\}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I see. Though, both are bounded in $\ell^2$ correct?

Comment: Yes. The first $is$ an open ball and the second is a subset of the open ball $B(0,2)$.

Comment: Every unit ball is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any $A\subset l^2$ is bounded

iff $\exists a>0 \,\forall x,y\in A\,(\,\|x-y\|<a)$

iff $\exists b>0 \,\forall x,y\in A\,(\,\|x-y\|\le b)$

iff $\exists c>0 \, \exists z\in l^2\,\forall x\in A\,(\,\|x-z\|<c)$

iff $\exists d>0\,\exists w\in l^2\,\forall x\in A\,(\|x-w\|\le d).$

This definition applies to any normed linear space, And also to any metric space with metric $\rho,$ if you replace $\|x-y\|$ (etc.) with $\rho (x,y).$

Comment: With the exception of the $empty$ metric space, where the 3rd & 4th conditions do not apply.